# Iteration copying over itself on loop

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using [ACF's update_sub_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/) function to add content from a loop to a child repeater field.

I've got it to a point where the data is being added to the child repeater but it's overwriting itself. It only ever updates the first row in the child repeater so I only ever see the last loop through.

I'm iterating the parent repeater using `$counter`, but when I try to add an iteration to the child repeater it breaks the function. Like so:

```
update_sub_field( array($field_key, $counter, $sub_field_key, $rowcount), $value, $post_id );
```

I've tried another function `add_sub_row`... this adds the correct number of rows to the child repeater's but doesn't add the data.

Here's my full code:

```
// Product Code Titles
$rows = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0)->find('tr');
$field_key = "field_5ae0882f9d6f9";
$sub_field_key = "field_5ae088999d6fb";

if(empty($rows)){
    die("Empty array");
}

$titles = array(); // aka your $data

// here we fetch the first row and iterate to get titles
$row = current($rows);
foreach ($row->find('td') as $cell) {
    $titles[] = array("column_title" => strip_tags($cell->innertext));
}
update_field( $field_key, $titles, $post_id );

// here we continue iteration starting from second row
$value = array();
$rowcount = 1;
while($row = next($rows)){

    $cells = $row->find('td');
    $columnsCount = count($cells);
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
      $value[] = array("text" => strip_tags($cell->innertext));
      update_sub_field( array($field_key, $counter, $sub_field_key), $value, $post_id );
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
      $value = array();
      $counter++;
    }

  $rowcount++;

}
```

Just to give some context, I'm recreating this table with the cell data being put into a child repeater field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much on this subject so hope this helps someone else.

I stopped it appending to the `$value` array, changed the function to `update_sub_row` and added a counter to iterate the child repeater rows.

Here's the full code:

```
// Product Code Titles
$rows = $html->find('div[class=product-table]', 0)->find('tr');
$field_key = "field_5ae0882f9d6f9";
$sub_field_key = "field_5ae088999d6fb";

if(empty($rows)){
    die("Empty array");
}

$titles = array(); // aka your $data

// here we fetch the first row and iterate to get titles
$row = current($rows);
foreach ($row->find('td') as $cell) {
    $titles[] = array("column_title" => strip_tags($cell->innertext));
}
update_field( $field_key, $titles, $post_id );

// here we continue iteration starting from second row
$value = array();
$rowcount = 1;
while($row = next($rows)){

    $cells = $row->find('td');
    $columnsCount = count($cells);
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
      $value = array("field_5ae088b79d6fc" => strip_tags($cell->innertext));
      update_sub_row( array($field_key, $counter, $sub_field_key), $rowcount, $value, $post_id );
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
      $value = array();
      $counter++;
    }

  $rowcount++;

}
```